# groovy array remove the brackets

Tags: list, groovy, brackets

```
  def colarray=[]
                    def num
                    def newRole = rolecol.split(',')
                    def len = newRole.size()
                    println "$newRole,$len"
                    for (num = 0; num < len; num++) {
                        def col = "col"
                        col="$col"+newRole[num]
                        colarray.add(col)

                    }
                    println colarray
                    sql.eachRow("select col01,$colarray from read_csv where col01=? and col${usercol}!=? ", [file.name,""])
```

i want save col1..col11 into array and call it from select statement, but the problem is that $colarray has the brackets with it (like [col03, col04, col05, col06, col07, col08, col09, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15, col16, col17, col18, col19, col20, col21, col22, col23, col24, col25, col26, col27, col28, col29, col30, col31, col32, col33]
), so now i want to remove them, anyone can help with it???thx

Answer (score 1):

the `[]` are there, because you are doing an implicit `toString` on the list.  use `colarray.join(',')`

Comment: def aa=colarray.join(',')
                        println aa
                       // sql.eachRow("select col01,$aa from read_csv where col01=? and col${usercol}!=? ", [file.name,""])
hi i edit it like this but get error, pls view following comment

Answer (score 0):

```
def colarray = rolecol.tokenize(',').collect { "col$it" }.join(', ')
```

Then you will also need to escape your sql:

```
sql.eachRow("select col01, ${Sql.expand(colarray)} from read_csv where col01 = ? and ${Sql.expand('col' + usercol)} != ? ", [file.name,""])
```

Comment: hi i tried it but get same error message with my codes..pls check my answer..if you can help thx again